# ExtJS 4: JSONRPC 2.0 as store protocol?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I would like to implement a graphical user interface on the basis of ExtJS version 4. The web service I want to use provides data as result sets of jsonrpc-2.0 calls.

I cannot find anything in the docs on how to do this. Do I use AJAX proxy? If so, how do I generate the proper POST requests for jsonrpc?

*edited to clarify*: **I already have a means to do jsonrpc2 requests** to the server and the server answers with a proper response. So I guess I really need a store that calls custom functions and defines callbacks or some such. An Invocation of that mechanism looks like:

```
jsonrpc2.call("method_name", parameterObject, 
        function(success, data_or_error_object) { /* callback code */ })
```

with method_name like "create", "update", etc., the parameterObject is mostly a normal javascript object with named parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should look at `Ext.Direct`.  While it is not exactly what you're looking for, it is very similar to `JSON-RPC`, so looking at the source code for `Ext.data.DirectStore` should give you some hints about how you can implement a `JSONRpc` store.

Comment: Forgot to review this question, but that was actually what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.js store has a proxy which you can define urls for api actions for CRUD operations, but this centres around providing a URL for the actions which would commonly be a server side method to perform the actions.

If you're using a local server proxy, such as type: 'ajax' you can then call the 'sync()' method on the store to send off the requests for each operation to the urls/methods defined on the store.

Is it critical that you keep the 'call' function you've defined, as I don't think you'd need it in this situation.

If you wanted to make these calls using JSONP you can define a store with a 'type' of JSONP like this example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'User',
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url : 'http://domainB.com/users'
    }
});

store.load();
```

The JSONP proxy isn't really used for operations other than load though, if you want to manipulate records on a remote server you have to wrap the data into parameters and this isn't the advised route.

Comment: well the service provides data ONLY through jsonrpc. what if I have no influence over that? does it mean extjs just cannot be used because of its inflexible assumptions?

Comment: If you only want the service to provide data, as in you only need to read from the service, then you just setup a JSONP proxy as per my example. If you wish to do read/write style operations then you will have to construct a JSONP store and ensure that on the requests you append your data in the form of parameters. JSONP isn't really meant to send data to other domains, more to read from them.

Comment: the jsonp proxy loads via GET request (script tag). I repeatedly stated I wanted to do json- **RPC** (emphasis added) calls via POST. please elaborate how I can do _RPC_ calls with jsonp? The calls are not crossdomain.

Comment: My apologies I did read the original post wrong. In order to ensure requests are sent with HTTP Post, you can use either the ajax proxy or rest proxy and call .sync() this will batch up the requests and call the appropriate URl's defined in the store API with the relevent data.

Comment: It seems you just don't understand what the actual problem is. AJAX proxy won't help, AJAX proxy won't properly encode request, and I don't have a problem to understand how AJAX proxy works. The problem is EXTJS CANNOT DO IT with its built-in proxies at all. Your advice is appreciated, thank you. I will leave the question open for now.